# Firebase Auth with unity creates new user in every start

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

I'm using firebase anonymous authantication for my unity project.
As i always did when project is started i'm sending request to firebase for authantication,
but on my last project (which uses firebase sdk 6.16.0) my request creates new user everytime.

Here is some code about how i'm sending my request

```
Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth auth = Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
            auth.SignInAnonymouslyAsync().ContinueWith((task =>
            { 
                if (task.IsCanceled)
                { 
                 Debug.Log("task cancelled");
                    return;
                }
                if (task.IsFaulted)
                { 
                 Debug.Log("task cancelled");
                    return;
                }
                if (task.IsCompleted)
                {
                    Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser userr = task.Result; 
                    firebaseUserId = userr.UserId;  
                    Debug.Log("firebaseUserId");
                    Debug.Log(firebaseUserId); 
                    //every opening returns new uniq id here.
                     
                }

            }));
```

On firebase authantication panel i only activated anonymous login. any suggestions?
Or is there any way to downgrade unity firebase version? i've tried to import old version which i was using on my last game (sdk 6.15.2) but there is some errors on resolver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, every time you call `SignInAnonymouslyAsync` you'll create a new user and the last one will be basically lost (it's more or less a random hash - anonymous as it's name suggests).

I'll typically do something like:

```
using System;
using Firebase.Auth;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;

public class Login : MonoBehaviour
{
    public UnityEvent OnSignInFailed = new UnityEvent();
    public UserSignedInEvent OnUserSignedIn = new UserSignedInEvent();

    public async void TriggerLogin()
    {
        var auth = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
        var user = auth.CurrentUser;
        if (user == null)
        {
            try
            {
                user = await auth.SignInAnonymouslyAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.LogException(e);
                OnSignInFailed.Invoke();
                return;
            }
        }

        // user definitely should not be null!
        if (user == null)
        {
            OnSignInFailed.Invoke();
            Debug.LogWarning("User still null!?");
            return;
        }

        var userName = user.UserId;
        OnUserSignedIn.Invoke(userName);
        Debug.Log($"Logged in as {userName}");
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class UserSignedInEvent : UnityEvent<string>
    {
    }
}
```

Note that for this code snippet, `TriggerLogin` is a public method so I can chain it off of a `UnityEvent` in the Unity editor.

[image: Screenshot of the Unity Editor showing TriggerLogin being selected from a Unity Event]

Answer (score 0):

Try and Put it some kind of check to find if used is already logged in. If yes, then do a silent login, if no then use anonymous login.

Currently you are straightaway logging in user even if they logged in last time they opened the Application.

Try this link: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/266#issuecomment-447981995